# Cannot Implicitly Convert Bitmap to Images or Images to Images

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, embedded-resource

I just wrote thsi code to have an access to images

```
private Bitmap[] hi = { HangmanUrdu.Properties.Resources._4, HangmanUrdu.Properties.Resources._5, HangmanUrdu.Properties.Resources._6, HangmanUrdu.Properties.Resources._7, HangmanUrdu.Properties.Resources._8, HangmanUrdu.Properties.Resources._9, HangmanUrdu.Properties.Resources._10 };
```

but when i want to increment the index and get these images in my picture box

```
// wg is just a counter;
pictureBox1.Image = hi { wg}; i
```

t throws me an error saying

> cannot implicitly convert Bitmap to images

I also tried to change my array from bitmap to image but then it shows me error that cannot convert Images to Images.

Comment: `pictureBox1.Image = hi[0];`. You should convert a Bitmap resource to a Bitmap object before adding it to collection. `Properties.Resources` is a factory: a new Bitmap is created each time you ask for one.

Comment: a small code would be nice

Comment: It means that you need to cast explicitly: `pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)(hi [ wg]);` - I assume you need brackets, not braces..

Answer (score 1):

Create a `List<Bitmap>` - as a Field, here - or any other type that fits the design (a class property, for example).
Fill the `List<Bitmap>` in a Form's constructor with the Bitmap objects needed in that context, creating a new Bitmap from the resource object:

```
private List<Bitmap> hi = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.hi = new List<Bitmap>()
    {
        new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._4),
        new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._5)
    };
}
```

The assign a Bitmap to a control's Image property when you need to:

```
pictureBox1.Image = hi[1];
```

You could also build a specialized class that hold these references, so you can access them with different *naming conventions*.
For example:

```
private List<BitmapResource> BitmapResources = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.BitmapResources = new List<BitmapResource>()
    {
        new BitmapResource(new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._4), "Logo"),
        new BitmapResource(new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._5), "Watermark")
    };
}

internal class BitmapResource
{
    public BitmapResource(Bitmap bitmap, string imageName)
    {
        this.Image = bitmap;
        this.Name = imageName;
    }
    public Bitmap Image { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Then, when needed:

By index:

```
pictureBox1.Image = BitmapResources[0].Image;
```

By name (simplified):

```
pictureBox1.Image = BitmapResources.FirstOrDefault(res => res.Name == "Logo").Image;
```

Comment: i used this and it is increment images in Picture box  

 wg++;
            if (wg == 1)
            {
                HM.Image = HangmanUrdu.Properties.Resources._4;
            }

Comment: Using the first or the second method, you can increment your indexer and take the image from the List: `wg++; pictureBox1.Image = hi[wg];`. Add the Bitmaps in the order you need them.